# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// Error

Tags: flutter

I got error

> invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///upload/subject/Account.png

I got other all data from api but when I fetch an image it throws above error.

Json response as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "subject": [
    {
      "subject_id": "5e32874c714fa",
      "subject_name": "Account",
      "image": "upload/subject/Account.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5da9ff659fb7c",
      "subject_name": "Biology",
      "image": "upload/subject/03_logo-1164x484.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5da9ff990b1c6",
      "subject_name": "Chemisty",
      "image": "upload/subject/02_logo-1168x490.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5de76afbd064e",
      "subject_name": "Computer",
      "image": "upload/subject/07_logo-1169x486.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    },
    {
      "subject_id": "5d788906c431b",
      "subject_name": "Devsatya Paperset March 2020",
      "image": "upload/subject/04_logo-1174x491.png",
      "active": "1",
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344"
    }
  ]
}
```

And i created Model Class from app.quicktype.io/ as below.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final subjectByUser = subjectByUserFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

SubjectByUser subjectByUserFromJson(String str) => SubjectByUser.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String subjectByUserToJson(SubjectByUser data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SubjectByUser {
    SubjectByUser({
        this.success,
        this.subject,
    });

    int success;
    List<Subject> subject;

    factory SubjectByUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SubjectByUser(
        success: json["success"],
        subject: List<Subject>.from(json["subject"].map((x) => Subject.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "subject": List<dynamic>.from(subject.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Subject {
    Subject({
        this.subjectId,
        this.subjectName,
        this.image,
        this.active,
        this.standardId,
        this.mediumId,
    });

    String subjectId;
    String subjectName;
    String image;
    String active;
    String standardId;
    String mediumId;

    factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        subjectId: json["subject_id"],
        subjectName: json["subject_name"],
        image: json["image"],
        active: json["active"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "subject_id": subjectId,
        "subject_name": subjectName,
        "image": image,
        "active": active,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
    };
}
```

The Function as below.

```
Future<List<Subject>> getSubjectByUser() async {
    final subjectUrl =
        '$baseUrl/subject/get_by_user_plan?user_id=609cab2cd5b6c&order_id=1620889722609cd07a601af469889697609cab2cd5b6c&standard_id=5d1594e283e1a&medium_id=5d15938aa1344';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(subjectUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final subjectData = subjectByUserFromJson(response.body);

      final List<Subject> subjects = subjectData.subject;
      return subjects;
    } else {
      return <Subject>[];
    }
  }
```

And View code as below.

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: null == _subjects ? 0 : _subjects.length,
        //itemCount: _subjects.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Subject subject = _subjects[index];

          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Image.network(subject.image),
              title: Text(subject.subjectName),
            ),
          );
        });
```

So how can i get image in list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In network image, you just called `subject.image` that means you call "upload/subject/02_logo-1168x490.png" but you missed adding base `url`. And you must use `shrinkWrap: true` under `ListView.builder`

```
ListTile(
              leading: Image.network("$baseUrl/$"subject.image"),// here will be changed need
              title: Text(subject.subjectName),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it works. Thenk you for your Help.....

It works for me as.

```
child: Image.network("$imageUrl" + subject.image),
```